# How to find, out of many days, 1 day that is most profitable on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, vlookup

Ok, I've been looking for this type of formula but not finding it. So here I am asking for help.

I'm a day trader on stocks and I want to analyze my performance. For example:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+
|      Days       | Profit/Loss  |  Per Day  | Per Day Pr/Loss | Best Day |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+
| Monday          | $100         | Monday    |           -1088 | Friday   |
| Tuesday         | -$50         | Tuesday   |           -3550 |          |
| Thursday        | $21          | Wednesday |            -958 |          |
| Monday          | $12          | Thursday  |              21 |          |
| Monday          | -$1200       | Friday    |            5715 |          |
| Wednesday       | -$1200       |           |                 |          |
| Friday          | $3200        |           |                 |          |
| Tuesday         | -$3500       |           |                 |          |
| Wednesday       | -$300        |           |                 |          |
| Wednesday       | $42          |           |                 |          |
| Wednesday       | $500         |           |                 |          |
| Friday          | $15          |           |                 |          |
| Friday          | $2500        |           |                 |          |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+
```

P/L according to days should be:

```
Mondays -$1088,  
Tuesdays -$3550,  
Wednesdays -$958,  
Thursdays $21,  
Fridays $5715
```

(How can I calculate this as well?)

And the most profitable days traded from the example above should be `FRIDAY`.

Now my question is, how can I formulate this so that it gives me `Friday` as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `QUERY` and `VLOOKUP` functions:

In cell `D2` place the following formula nad drag it down to cell `D6`

```
=QUERY($A$2:$C,"select sum(B) where A='"&$C2&"' label sum(B)''")
```

In cell `D2` place the following:

```
=Vlookup(max($D$2:$D),{$D$2:$D,$C$2:$C},2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the quick response and the edit.

Comment: Have you tried the solution given? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.